# Is 2 the best result?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I think many people have done this exercise in mathematical analysis.
I saw it from [this：Question 15](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~b89089/book/Rudin/Rudin_5.pdf)

Suppose $f(x)$ is a twice-differentiable real function on (-∞,+∞),
and $M_0$, $M_1$,$M_2$ are the least upper bounds of |$f(x)$|, |$f^{'}(x)$|, |$f^{''}(x)$|,
respectively, on (-∞,+∞).
As we can see, we can prove $$M_1^2\le2M_0M_2$$
A natural question is : Is 2 the best result for this inequality?Is there a more exact result?

Comment: Good question! In particular, one can ask this sub-question of your question: Does there exist a bounded, twice differentiable function 
$f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$
such that
$M_1^2=2M_0M_2$?

Comment: Thanks for replying! I think the example is hard to find.

Comment: I agree, it's not an easy question. I did _try_ to find an example. Based on a small sample, I don't think $k = 2$ is achievable. My guess is that the minimum value of $k$ for which the inequality is always satisfied is $k=1$.

Comment: I gave you $+1$ (it had been $-2$). I'm not sure why you got negative votes. Perhaps the down-votes were due to the fact that you showed no work. But in this case, your question is (1) clearly not a HW problem; (2) a question showing insight and curiosity; (3) simply stated and appealing, but possibly quite hard. Thus, in my opinion, the very _asking_ of the question deserves some credit.

Comment: By the way, for the pdf you referenced, are those _your_ solutions?

Comment: I'm glad for your comment.This is my first time to ask question on math stack exchange, it seems that I do think less before asking, next time I will pay more attention to this.The solutions are not mine,I just search them on google.I will keep exploring.

Comment: I used to think k=1 is right, but later I find an example:sin(x)/(x^2+1).For this function k is about 1.35

Comment: Interesting. When I get a chance, maybe tomorrow, I'll play with it some more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I know 2 is the best result, though the example for $M_1^2=2M_0M_2$ I haven't discovered, as it requires some knowledge I have not learnt.[Click here to see  Landau-Kolmogorov Constants.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Landau-KolmogorovConstants.html)